# Writing to a file in Node.JS inside an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs

I'm writing to a file inside a async function:

```
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
const fs = require('fs')

function parse(feed_url) {
    let parser = new Parser();
    (async () => {
        let feed = await parser.parseURL(feed_url);
        fs.writeFileSync('./output.json', JSON.stringify(feed), {
            encoding: "utf8",
            mode: 0o666
          })
    })();
    const data = fs.readFileSync('./output.json', 'utf8')
    fs.unlinkSync('./output.json');
    return data
}

console.log(parse('https://www.reddit.com/.rss'))
```

I now get the error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './output.json'
```

If wondering, I do need to write the file inside the async function, because of a package I'm using.

How can I write to a file inside an async function and then read that file outside that async?

UPDATE: Add full code.

Comment: perhaps the file hasn't been written yet ... show the code including when/how you read it

Comment: by the way, why is that IIFE `async` anyway? you're not awaiting anything, and you're not using anything asynchronous, in fact, you're specifically using synchronous write ... your code probably works if you DON'T use `async`

Comment: You do not need to put `fs.writeFileSync()` into an `async` function.  That's an entirely synchronous operation.  And, to help you with the problem of the file not being there, we need to see the rest of the relevant code, including the code that tries to read the file and how it is run in relation to this code.  It could be a timing issue or it could be that the current working directory  has been changed or it could be that something else has removed the file or it could be a permission issue.  Right now, there's insufficient information ion your question to help further.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have much more code, which does use `async` and `await`, which is used to parse a rss feed, I simplified the code so that it would be easier to understand. You can check the package I'm using @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser

Comment: What I don't understand is why you need a file in the first place

Comment: Because the function itself wasn't an async, new variable values wouldn't save (if there was a way I didn't find one), and so saving to a file inside the async and then reading it outside was the way I came up with, but then I stumbled across this problem. However, turning the whole function into an async is much more efficient.

Comment: Well, you oversimplified your original question and left out the most important part (the actual asynchronous operations).  I really don't understand why people think they need to dumb down their questions when they post here - it's much better to err on the side of too much code included so we can see what is really going on.  Anyway, glad you got an answer now that you've included the important parts of the code.  Remember that all the relevant real code will always get you faster and more accurate answers.  Err on the side of too much code if you're not sure what is relevant.

Comment: And, if this is server-side code, you should NOT be using `fs.readFileSync()` or `fs.writeFileSync()` except in server initialization code.  Instead, use `await fs.promises.readFile()` and `await fs.promises.writeFile()` to keep all your file I/O asynchronous and non-blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make function parse async

Then your code is simple

```
async function parse(feed_url) {
    let parser = new Parser();
    let feed = await parser.parseURL(feed_url);
    fs.writeFileSync('./output.json', JSON.stringify(feed), {
        encoding: "utf8",
        mode: 0o666
      })
    const data = fs.readFileSync('./output.json', 'utf8')
    fs.unlinkSync('./output.json');
    return data
}

parse('https://www.reddit.com/.rss').then(console.log);
```

Of course ... why do you need a file!!!!

```
async function parse(feed_url) {
    let parser = new Parser();
    let feed = await parser.parseURL(feed_url);
    return JSON.stringify(feed)
}

parse('https://www.reddit.com/.rss').then(console.log);
```

Comment: It makes you wonder if they should be using `fs.promises.writeFile()` and `fs.promises.readFile()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I've stopped wondering about such things :p

Answer (score 0):

1. I think your path to the file should be `"output.json"` (according to the documentation of [node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)).
2. And since your are not using the await keyword in your code you could remove that too.

```
(() => {
        data = {
           value: 'value'
           value_2: 'value'
        }
        fs.writeFileSync('output.txt', JSON.stringify(data), {
            encoding: "utf8",
            mode: 0o666
        })
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please align code (`output.txt`) and description (`output.json`)?

Comment: As stated in the question, I use the external library [rss-parser](https://npmjs.org/package/rss-parser) to parse an rss feed, which I export to a file. Because of this, I need to use an async, and so this doesn't work for the problem.